Routerlinks inside navigation component are not working, what am i doing wrong?
the routerLinks inside my sidenav component are not working. When i click on them nothing happens, and i get no error message. Can someone help me out?
app.component.html
 <div class="app-container flex">
 <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
 <div class="content">
   <app-header></app-header>
   <app-main></app-main>
 </div>

app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SidenavComponent } from './sidenav/sidenav.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular- 
fontawesome';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
standalone: true,
imports: [
CommonModule,
FontAwesomeModule,
SidenavComponent,
MainComponent,
HeaderComponent],
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'DemoProject';
}

sidenav.component.html
<nav class="sidenav" [@collapseState]="collapseState">
<button class="collapse-button" (click)="onCollapse()">
<fa-icon [icon]="faBars"></fa-icon>
</button>``
<ul>
<!--
<li><a href="#" [@menuItemState]="menuItemState">Menu Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" [@menuItemState]="menuItemState">Menu Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" [@menuItemState]="menuItemState">Menu Item 3</a></li>
-->
<li><a  routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a></li>
<li><a  routerLink="/flights" routerLinkActive="active">Flights</a></li>


<!-- Add more menu items as needed -->

sidenav.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger,state,style,animate,transition } from 
'@angular/animations';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { faBars } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';


@Component({
selector: 'app-sidenav',
standalone: true,
imports: [FontAwesomeModule],
templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
styleUrl: './sidenav.component.scss',
animations: [
trigger('collapseState', [
  state('collapsed', style({
    width: '60px' // Width for collapsed state
  })),
  state('expanded', style({
    width: '15vw' // Width for collapsed state
  })),
  transition('collapsed => expanded', [
    animate('0.3s ease')
  ]),
  transition('expanded => collapsed', [
    animate('0.3s ease')
  ])
]
),
trigger('menuItemState', [
  state('shown', style({
    display: 'block'
  })),
  state('hidden', style({
    display: 'none' 
  })),
]
),
 ]
 })
 export class SidenavComponent {
 faBars = faBars;
 collapseState = 'expanded';
 iconState = 'hidden';
 menuItemState = 'shown'

 onCollapse() {
  this.collapseState == 'expanded' ? this.collapseState = 'collapsed' : 
 this.collapseState = 'expanded';
 this.iconState == 'hidden' ? this.iconState = 'shown' : this.iconState 
 = 'hidden';
 this.menuItemState == 'shown' ? this.menuItemState = 'hidden' : 
 this.menuItemState = 'shown';
 console.log(this.collapseState,this.menuItemState);
 }


} 

main.component.html
<div class="flex w-full ">
<p>main works!</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

app.routes.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from 
'./dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { FlightsComponent } from './flights/flights.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
{path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
{path: 'flights', component: FlightsComponent},

 ];

i guess my imports are wrong but i dont know what to do :(

Can you provide detailed info on what is not working? The link when clicked redirects to the URL but does not show the component? Missing/Not Found route? Do you get any error in the Browser DevTools console? Also do showing us what is your routes and how you register in RouterModule.

i edited the question now to provide more information

I believe your routerLinks are not working as you are not importing it in the SideNavComponent.
Make sure that you are importing RouterLink and RouterLinkActive.
import { RouterLink, RouterLinkActive } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FontAwesomeModule, RouterLink, RouterLinkActive],
  ...
})
export class SidenavComponent {
  ...
}

Demo @ StackBlitz

now i get this error in console:
core.mjs:6531 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute!
at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:1654:27)
at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3093:33)
at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3093:33)
at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3093:33)
at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:15265:36)
at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:5730:39)
at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:5778:12)
at ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:10548:19)

This seems like another issue in which you are using ActivatedRoute in the component. You need to import ActivatedRoute the same as how you import the RouterLink into the standalone component. Otherwise, you may import the whole RouterModule into the component.

cant import ActivatedRoute: import { ActivatedRoute, RouterLink, RouterLinkActive } from '@angular/router';. ActivatedRoute is redhighlighted
VS Code says: Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModules.

Hi, sorry, shouldn't import the ActivatedRoute into the component. Import RouterModule instead. If you still encounter the issue, would be create to reproduce in StackBlitz.
